# Django - url structure

Tags: python, django, url

How should I design url's or views to keep url structure like in the example below?

```
example.com/location/
example.com/category/
example.com/location/category/

url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<town>[\w\-_]+)/$', TownView.as_view(), name="town_detail"),
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name="category_list"),
```

When I try to access url under category I am getting routed to TownView which is acceptable because the url patterns are almost the same.

Should the category be put under example.com/c/category/ ?

Edit:

I did resolve my problem in a way I'm showing below.
All answers are really good and helpful.

I will have to validate how this solution will act and check if it's causing any problems.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', BrowseView.as_view(), name="category_list"),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', BrowseView.as_view(), name="town_detail"),


class BaseView(ListView):
    queryset = Advert.objects.all().select_related('category', )
    template_name = "adverts/category_view.html"


class BrowseView(BaseView):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(BrowseView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            object_list = qs.filter(location__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        else:
            category_values_list = category.get_descendants(include_self=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
            object_list = qs.filter(category__in=category_values_list)

        return object_list
```

Comment: Both are really important and I've seen some websites which handle location and categories in the way I want. 

Would it be correct to create a view which tries to get a category or a town?
It would generate additional queries but in my opinion it would do the trick.

Comment: Create it would generate extra overhead to the application. Like creating an intermediary view, check (probably database hit) if is location or category and then route the request. Everything can be done, but I rather KISS :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the regular expressions are the same and Django **takes the first one that match** so you'll have problems. You can do some tweaks to differentiate them. For instances, that one you suggest is nice. You may also be more verbose in order to be more user friendly and design them like this:

```
example.com/location/<location name>
example.com/category/<category name>
example.com/location/<location name>/category/<category name>
```

That way you should do with this:

```
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^/location/(?P<town>[\w\-_]+)/$', TownView.as_view(), name="town_detail"),
url(r'^/category/(?P<category_slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', CategoryView.as_view(), name="category_list"),
# this one I supposed you'll need for the third one (sort of)
url(r'^/location/(?P<town>[\w\-_]+)/category/(?P<category_slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', Location_CategoryView.as_view(), name="location_category_list"),
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both solution are really helpful and I can't decide which one should I accept. I also updated first post with my idea for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I depends on the priority. I have the use case  using username and the regular URLs.So what i planned was the to give less priority to the users.

Two things to keep in mind:

**1.Priority**

If you think location is more important give priority to location.
But if both are important the only option is to use:

```
r'^(?P/location/<town>[\w\-_]+)/$'
r'^(?P/category/<category_slug>[\w\-_]+)/$'
```

**2.Parent-Child**

It also depends on the parent and child relationship.So, you will know which is more important.

```
/location/category/
/category/location/
```